# Hard to understanding d3.range.js and d3.scale.linear

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, range

I know how to use [range.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/arrays/range.js) and [d3.scale.linear](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/scale/linear.js), also know domain and range .

but when I read the code in range.js and  linear.js, I was so confused that why it looks so complicated and mysterious：
such as the code in linear.js：

```
step = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log(span / m) / Math.LN10)),
err = m / span * step;
// Filter ticks to get closer to the desired count.
if (err <= .15) step *= 10;
else if (err <= .35) step *= 5;
else if (err <= .75) step *= 2;
```

Generally，I implement the function by using  "ax + b = y" ，such as:

```
domain(inputMin, inputMax); 
stick = 4;

a = (inputMax-inputMin)/stick;
for(i = 0; i<a; i++) 
{
    arr[] = i*a+inputMin;
}
```

so why d3 use Math.log (Math.pow...) to get the 'step'?

what the code means and does？

*Thanks for any help you can offer.*

Comment: The straightforward code you've posted will give you ticks, but not necessarily nice ones. That is, if your domain is 0 to 2 with 3 ticks for example, you'll get ticks at 0.6666666 and 1.333333. D3 tries to make nice ticks (i.e. at "round" numbers), hence the additional code.

Answer (score 1):

I had to write unit tests for this algorithm last week. Here my explanation:

```
// Approximate the step to the closest power of ten by transforming to the
// commom log scale, truncating the mantissa, and transforming back.
step = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log(span / m) / Math.LN10)),

// Calculate how closely the step covers the span of the domain.
err = (m * step) / span;

// Given the coverage of the current step against the domain span, multiply
// (if necessary) by a constant to get closer to the desired tick count.
if (err <= 0.15) step *= 10;
else if (err <= 0.35) step *= 5;
else if (err <= 0.75) step *= 2;
```